# Why Godot over Cryengine, UE4, Armory3d or Unity3d?

Tags: unity, unreal-4, godot, cryengine

Godot have a low performance in linux systems and lack of functionalities? This appear not been in account when peoples vote for him over other engines and i wonther whi.
I know it is under MIT lisence, but the others engines have a very permisive licences and in some cases they help you with funding for your games.
I ask this because i have maded survey on google plus about a selection of engines, and people still bote for godot over other engines. I want to select an engine for my future games, and when i compared, godot's not get a good place.

Comment: Until Godot fixes its iOS build pipeline, I wouldn't even consider it. Maybe it's fixed since I last looked, but at the time it was horrible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although usually questions like "what software is better" are off-topic, because the answer is almost always "try them all, and pick your favourite", I think this one could be an exception so I'll attempt to answer it.

- From my experience, Godot does not have low performance on Linux. I have one of the cheapest laptops on the market, and run Arch Linux, and Godot runs fine (far better than Unity - I haven't tried the other engines you mentioned).
- Being open source is a massive plus for Linux users. It doesn't automatically make the software immune to malicious behaviour, but it's better when the developer says "You don't believe me? Check the code!" instead of "You don't believe me? I tell the truth, I promise!", especially since companies have taken advantage of that in the past.
- MIT license is another plus, you make a game using Godot, you own it. There is nobody to cause you legal trouble, nobody to take part of your profits (As far as I remember that's how MIT license works).
- Having tried Godot, I enjoy the C++ inheritance-oriented design, as it's closer to traditional game design before using engines (at least for me). I find Unity's component-based system a "it just works" kinda system. On Godot, if I want to do something the language didn't intend me to do, it feels like I can do it, on Unity I always end up going to the forums, and there's been times that the feature I seek is not supported "By design".
- Personally I enjoy Godot's attitude. They are more like "We made an engine, feel free to use it, and if you want, donate back to us". Although I can't blame other engines for asking profits, since the people work hard on them. This also allows people that can't afford much money, to experiment with Godot. Having said that I'm aware that lately some engines moved to a different model where you only pay if you make enough profit.

Having said all of that, I use Unity at work, and I'm more used to it than any other engine. I've used Godot on my free time but not to the same extend. Also the points I made do not say that Godot is any better than other engines, it simply states I would understand why a person would choose to support it over other engines.

Comment: i can not give you points because my reputation, but it's a good answer, but i steel have performance issues on xubuntu, i have to say not in the editor but in the player, my FPS drop to 10 in the FPP sample scene. I'm using my NVidea driver

Comment: @ErnestoAlfonso do you have low-end or high-end computer? The player should be way more resource intensive than the editor, so for a low-end computer it's not surprising for the player to run slower. If however on the same computer Unity's player runs faster, then yeah, that's a minus on Godot. Also if you think an answer solves your question, you can mark it as correct without spending your reputation, but I think you have to wait some time since the question was asked, to give chance to other people to give better/alternative answers.

Comment: i have high-end computer, i think is a driver problem, but how bad can be a driver to do this kind of performance issues. I'm going to give a chance to godot